# Unable to remove login item from Users & Groups startup list

Tags: system-settings, login-items

I have an item in my "Login Items" list (`System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items`) that refuses to be removed. When highlighted, the minus button grays out. The "hide" toggle is also grayed out. There is no option in [this specific app](http://cma.dl.playstation.net/cma/mac/en/index.html) to disable load on startup. Why is it showing this way and is there a general way (override) to remove such apps?

[image: Login Items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Content Manager Assistant added the login item to `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` instead of `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`.

I was able to remove the login item by deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` and restarting (logging out and back in wasn't enough).